# Using PHP Regex or DOM, how to get web page's <TITLE>?</TITLE> with eol or newline in between the tags?

Tags: php, html, regex, curl, dom

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the title from an html page containing the following:

```
<title>Breaking <--- *EOL
- News</title>
```

> *Note: there's an invisible EOL or new line break after the word 'Breaking'.

I've tried just about every regex possible dealing with eol, but nothing seems to be working. It always returns nothing.

```
preg_match('/\<title.*?\>(.*?)\<\/title\>/si', $str, $match);
preg_match('/(?s)\<title.*?\>(.*?)\<\/title\>/i', $str, $match)

$titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

this regex works in many cases of grabbing the title correctly but the eol in between the tags always fails no matter what I try.

Any meaningful step to a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the DOM approach? Works fine here ~ https://eval.in/1047266

Comment: Your first version works: https://ideone.com/s5u1wT

Comment: @Adriano The multiline flag is for making `^` and `$` match line beginning and end. The `s` flag is what he needs, and he already has it.

Comment: @Barmar I forked the actual html containing the original source code: https://ideone.com/67ICS3 it doesn't work!

Comment: @dpark123 well yeah, your string has unescaped quotes. Fixed here ~ https://ideone.com/4ibFCT

Comment: @Phil it was due to unescaped quotes, thanks, my bad.

Answer (score -1):

Try CHecked and working fine.

```
preg_match('/\<title\>(.*?)\<\/title\>/ism', $str, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Comment: I have checked and its working fine. Please check @dpark123

Answer (score -2):

I coded this real quick

```
<?php
$title = '<title>Breaking
- News</title>';

preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/is', $title, $match);

echo $match[0]."\n";
echo $match[1]."\n";
```

Hope it helps.